# Understand and developing firmware - IDE help

Tags: firmware

Lately I've been working on tweaking firmware to fix functions on my printer.  A few of my biggest issues are lack of understanding of C and finding out how the multiple cpp and h files are linked.  Most of what I am doing is easy enough to do with copy and paste but with most firmwares having 30+ individual files it's hard to find where each parameter comes from or goes to.

I've been looking at Eclipse with an Arduino plugin as well as Visual Studio (or Atmel Studio) with the Visual Micro plugin.  What I would like is an easy way to view where each parameter is used, maybe highlight the parameter and it shows all instances or something similar?  Is there any IDE that offers something like that or is everyone using the Arduino IDE for firmware development?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about 3D printing, but a General programming question. Please Ask this on [so].

Comment: It is about 3D printing, very unlikely to receive an answer about firmware with multiple cpp and h files written for Arduino in a programming community.

Comment: What specifically would you like to modify in the firmware? That might be more related to this forum! :)

Comment: HI, I have just come across this question, and I think it is rather useful, for two reasons. (1) We seem to be changing the scope of SE 3D Printing, as per one of your meta posts and [Game plan - What is on-topic?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/game-plan-what-is-on-topic?cb=1), and 3D Printing related coding *would* be on-topic *now*, and (2) Users new to 3D printing will probably encounter having to upgrade their firmware at some point, so a question about that here would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Marlin - assuming that is the firmware you are using - is a standard C++ (the big brother of C) project that can be opened and compiled in the Arduino IDE, but also - at least - edited lots of other IDEs.

Depending on your OS, there are several alternatives. Visual Studio, Atmel Studio, Qt Creator, XCode, Eclipse, Visual Studio Code, Atom, Sublime Text and the Arduino IDE are just some of them.

I also believe that this question should be moved to StackOverflow. However, if you have questions as to how you can make *specific* modification to Marlin, this forum is the right place to ask. If that is the case, consider reformulating your question!